# Change virtual Windows desktop without the Windows Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop

I have a PC with Windows 10 installed. For some reasons I use a keyboard without the Windows key. The default keystrokes is `Ctrl + Win + Right Arrow` (or Left).

But since my keyboard doesn't have the Win key, this is not an option for me. How can I define another fast move between the virtual desktops. Preferred keys would be Ctrl+Shift+Fn for the desktop #n.

*Edit:* If the Fn keys are special and can't be use as intended, other key combinations would also do the job.

Comment: There are plenty of keyboards without the Windows or super keys.  Some people love their older keyboards.  There are modern keyboards without them, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [similar programs](http://autohotkey%20alternative) to accomplish this.  You can assign the `Windows key` to another key, or create a script to emulate the keypresses necessary.

Comment: @harper - That would be outside the scope of Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, at https://superuser.com/help/on-topic I found that questions about "computer software" are in scope. Of course "computer software" is a wide area, and I could ask for any application software. But the question for some lines to switch the virtual desktop doesn't look as to broad for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), one possible solution to try would be e.g.:

*ex. desktop_switcher.ahk*

```
^+f4:: Send ^{Win}{Left}
^+f9:: Send ^{Win}{Right}
```

Where:

- `^+f4` and `^+f9` are your desired hotkeys. These would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, respectively. You can of course change <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> to any keys desired.
- These combinations would map to `^{Win}{Left}` and `^{Win}{Right}` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>). In this case, {`Win}` would be the (missing) <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

> Preferred keys would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> for the desktop #n.

I don't believe there are any "quick switch" key combinations for specific Windows desktops (at least as far as I am aware).

**Notes**

- The suggested solution requires that <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> be pressed with e.g. <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> to trigger. That is, you cannot simply hold <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

---

*References*

*[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)*

*[Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)*